# My wifi driver MT7630E seems to work fine during install and then tells me error

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, 16.04, modprobe

The route I went was straight from `https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796` website.

Now follow the instructions below:

1. extract the archive in your Downloads directory (or any other directory).
2. In terminal run:

cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E-release        (change the path if you extracted in another folder)

3. now run these commands one by one:

sudo chmod +x install
sudo ./install

The following is what I did

```
cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E-release
sudo chmod +x install
sudo ./install
```

and this is what I got

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7630e': Required key not available

I have tried dozens of other methods to get my wifi driver up and running and Im losing patience. I will take any suggestions. Please! Thank you!

Comment: Try disabling SecureBoot - also look in the "Additional drivers" utility, enabling it may be quite easy, esp. if it worked during the install. Maybe you need to reboot at least once after the install, too.

Comment: ok so i did the SecureBoot. but now it says modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7630e': Invalid argument

Comment: Hmm, In that case, I don't know. Did you look in the "Additional drivers" utility, though ?

Comment: Yes, there was nothing there unfortunately

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Theres alot of information in that command what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: This is what I'm getting back Jul  5 19:49:44 Talos kernel: [ 5800.599642] mt7630e: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
Jul  5 19:49:44 Talos kernel: [ 5800.599643] mt7630e: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
Jul  5 19:49:44 Talos kernel: [ 5800.599650] mt7630e: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
Jul  5 19:49:44 Talos kernel: [ 5800.599652] mt7630e: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)